# Make accordion js better

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I've wrote a simple accordion faqs list using jQuery, but looking for some feedback on ways to improve it better.

My mark-up looks something like this:

```
<ul class="faqs">
   <li><h4>Question</h4>
       <div class="answer">answer</div>
   </li>
   <li><h4>Question</h4>
       <div class="answer">answer</div>
   </li>
   <li><h4>Question</h4>
       <div class="answer">answer</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My JS looks something like this:

```
var question = $('.faqs h4');
question.click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

All .answer divs are set to display:none on page load, but if js is disabled, all .answer div would be shown by default.

Cheers

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this.

Comment: How are you applying the `display: none;`? Because adding display none via js means: no js > no hiding.. so how about defining it with pure css?

Comment: @Joonas, I fail to mention that I'm using modernizer to check if the browser supports js, so if it does, it appends .js class to the body tag and then i do a 'display:none' on .js .answer.

Comment: Hmmn and I failed to read the question properly. I thought you were wondering how to keep the answers always hidden.. -- Well, there is this beta website where your question would fit like an eye into an eye socket... or aomething http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and I think you'd need to specify it a bit more.. What is it that you want from the code? Currently the code is so small that there is hardly anything to improve. One thing that comes to mind replace the click event with on http://api.jquery.com/on/ ..and the var seems to be kinda useless since you only use it once.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding `$(".answer").slideUp()` so that only one accordion item can be open at a time:

```
var question = $('.faqs h4');
question.click(function() {
    $(".answer").slideUp();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

(Also, maybe add a little style, eg the `:hover` pseudo-class.  Maybe add some other animations.)

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9MQC/5/)

Comment: Only one item shows everytime, why is it necessary to make all .answers slide up?

Comment: @calebo just to make it so that when you open one, the previously open one closes.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, why to try yourself with something from scratch when **there's so many good accordions out there** ...

Did you try the **Bootstrap Collapse**?

> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Simple markup and you can use as part of the hole Bootstrap Framework, or [simply use it **independently**](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-collapse.js) from anything else (you need jQuery though)

Comment: There are multiple reasons to make something like an accordion yourself: 1.For learning purposes. 2.The code is your own code ( Proud moment in any coders life ). 3.You can right away code it to be as complex or as simple as you want.

Comment: I prefer to be proud of putting all to work than spend time on something so simple that I can accomplish with others, gives me also joy to mention others opensource code on my project. But that's only me! :)

Comment: I'm looking to learn and improve my js, so using a library for something so simple is over the top.

Comment: it's the best way to learn ... see others code and improve your's!

Comment: so, you never learned from examples...? Wow, you're my hero then!